# laravel errors "get_cfg_var()" has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, laravel, email, passwords

I am using Laravel and I want to send email forgot the password.

I did it by localserver but in the online host I get this error from Laravel:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>
> (E_UNKNOWN) Uncaught ErrorException: get_cfg_var() has been disabled
>   for security reasons

My .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME='421d....a5682e0'
MAIL_PASSWORD='7b4f....353be7'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My Emailcontroller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->email;
        Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => 'Reset Your Password ', 'content'` `=> $request->_token ], function ($message) use ($data)
        {
            // dd($data);
            $message->from('info@ABC.com', 'ABC');
            $message->subject(' (Reset Password)');
            $message->to($data);
        });

        return view('auth.passwords.email')->with(['message' => 'Reset Email sent, Please check your inbox']);
    }
}
```

thanks alot.

Comment: which hosting provider are you using? This is an issue related to your host. Some hosts disable certain functions which might be unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You must contact your machine host provider, because he blocked some potentially dangerous PHP functions. Or if you have administrator rights, maybe you can do it by yourself (though I really doubt it). Look for a line with

`disable_functions`

in your php config file (php.ini) and make available the offending function.

Comment: where should I search for "disabled_functions"?

Comment: Man... the answer cannot be more explicit. In the php.ini file. If you cannot access the file system through ssh console, there must be some way in the cpanel system to do it. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions